# Upgrade pandas 0.10 to 0.12 in Pyzo 2013b

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using Pyzo 2013b. It comes bundled with pandas 0.10.0. There is quite a bit of functionality from pandas 0.12 I would like to use (particularly formatting times etc).

Has anyone updated to pandas 0.12 in the Pyzo package? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

Pyzo [ships with pip](http://www.pyzo.org/packages.html), so you ought to be able to:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```